# Django Rest Framework, partial update

Tags: django, django-rest-framework

Ok so I have a very simple question i need to create a partial update,and it shows me an unresolved reference, I know why but cannot seem to understand this partial way method in django rest framework:

```
for ad in AdsId:
    AdsImagesSerializer(ads,data=ad_id, partial=True)
```

as you can see for each of these i want to partial update a field in the table which is called **ads**, but it keep saying unresolved reference of that field. I checked the documentation and there was this:

```
# Update `comment` with partial data
serializer = CommentSerializer(comment, data={'content': u'foo bar'}, partial=True)
```

who is the **comment** here ?

Comment: Is `ad_id` a dict?

Comment: no just an integer ex: 120

Comment: As you can see in the example, you need as the first argument, an object and as the second argument (`data`) a dict.

Answer (score 0):

If you check the beginning of the [serializer documentation](http://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/serializers/#declaring-serializers) you will find:

```
from datetime import datetime

class Comment(object):
    def __init__(self, email, content, created=None):
        self.email = email
        self.content = content
        self.created = created or datetime.now()

comment = Comment(email='leila@example.com', content='foo bar')
```